# Selection Sorting Algorithm for strings

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I was having trouble following the selected sorting algorithm for sorting strings in an array alphabetically. My code as it is, is a complete mess.

```
public class sorting {
public void getArray(String [] a) {
    int min = 0;
    int minIndex = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++ ) {
        for (int i = j; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (i == j) {
                 a[min] = a[j]; 
            }
            if (a[min].compareTo(a[i]) < 0) { // if current element is < lowest, assign new lowest.
                a[min] = a[i];
                minIndex = i;
            } // end of if
        } // end of INSIDE for

        a[minIndex] = a[j]; // place first element at the location of the smallest element.
        a[j] = a[min]; // place the smallest element value in the first spot. 
    } // end of OUTSIDE for    
}
```

Can anyone throughly explain to me their thought process in going on about this? For instance, what does the inner for loop do vs the outside? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply put, selection sort does the following:

1. Find the smallest element
2. Swap it with the first element
3. Find the second smallest element
4. Swap it with the second element
5. ... (and so on)

After steps 1 and 2, you know that the smallest element is in the first spot of the array. In step 3 you look for the second smallest element, which is the smallest if you start searching from the second position.

This is what the outer loop does: find the j-th smallest element and swap it with the element in spot j.

Now, how do you find the smallest element in an array? For that you need the inner loop. You keep track of the smallest element so far (and the index where you found it) and whenever you find a smaller element, you update the current smallest element (and the index where you found it).

---

There are two bugs in your code though:

1. When you're tracking the minimum element of an array, you are overwriting elements of your input. Instead of using `a[min]`, you should always use `min` directly (for that you need to change the type to `String` of course).
2. You should check if the `a[i]` is smaller than `min`, not the other way around.

```
if (i == j) {
    min = a[j];
}
if (a[i].compareTo(min) < 0) {
    min = a[i];
    minIndex = i;
}
```

and in the end:

```
a[minIndex] = a[j]; 
a[j] = min;
```

Comment: To make this a little more brain compatible: would the outer for loop be considered the "Macro?" as in where all the elements are in their final positions  and the inner for loop be considered the "Micro?" in that the smallest element is being found?

Comment: @Destinox yes, that logic is correct. And if you want to name those loops "macro" and "micro", be my guest ;)

Comment: Update: Strings are passed through this method. How would min (an integer) work in this scenario?

Comment: Min would not be able to work since the parameters are not strings.

Comment: @Destinox just change the type to `String` (also updated my answer).

Comment: Thank you, but I still have errors following the code: if I passed "Jacob, Alex, Zebo, and Kyle" I wouldn't be able to get them in alphabetical order. Instead I get the output of Zebo, Kyle, Jacob, Jacob.

Comment: @Destinox do not forget to initialize `min` (`String min = null`), and I found a second bug: when searching for the smallest element your comparison was the wrong way.

Comment: Wow! It worked. I fully understand what's going on. One final question however, if I'm working with Strings, why would I have to set the min to null instead of "" ?

Comment: @Destinox either would be fine. The initialization value is useless, since you always overwrite `min` before use anyway. However, the compiler is not smart enough to see that, so it warns you that `min` should have some value. You could set it to `"Destinox"` too ;)

Comment: Haha, I see! Thanks so much! I will always remember this.

Answer (score 0):

Sure I can have a go at explaining it to you. Firstly I'll do a bit of refactoring to make it a bit easier for me to explain. It is logically equivalent to the code you posted just with variables renamed and some logic split out into a second method rather than having an inner and outer loop.

This method iterates through the strings and, for each entry, calls `swapMinFromIndex`

```
public void sortStrings(String[] strings) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
        swapMinFromIndex(strings, i);
}
```

This method starts by assuming the first element is the smallest. It then goes through the remaining elements and if any are smaller than the current smallest it stores their index. Finally it swaps the smallest with the first (unless they are the same).

```
private void swapMinFromIndex(String[] strings, int start) {
    int indexOfMin = start;
    for (int i = start + 1; i < strings.length; i++) {
        if (strings[i].compareTo(strings[indexOfMin]) {
            indexOfMin = i;
        }
    }
    if (indexOfMin != start) {
        String tmp = strings[start];
        strings[start] = strings[indexOfMin];
        strings[indexOfMin] = tmp;
    }
}
```

So together these two methods continually look for the smallest element and swap it into position.